# Find match in id name and assign to to title tag

Tags: jquery

I have a grid on the page that has a series of dynamically generated radio buttons. All of the radio buttons have a similar ID name, with the exception being in the middle of the ID name - an incremental variable CTL## (ctl00, ctl01, etc.)

```
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl01_rdoCustomerSelect" type="radio" value="rdoCustomerSelect">
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl02_rdoCustomerSelect" type="radio" value="rdoCustomerSelect">
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl03_rdoCustomerSelect" type="radio" value="rdoCustomerSelect">
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl04_rdoCustomerSelect" type="radio" value="rdoCustomerSelect">
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl05_rdoCustomerSelect" type="radio" value="rdoCustomerSelect">
```

I have found the code to match the ID if it begins / ends with a specific pattern, but cant figure out how to extract the matching pattern and assign it to an attribute.

My end goal is to have the  tag formatted as follows...

```
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl01_rdoCustomerSelect" type="radio" value="rdoCustomerSelect" title="rdo_ctl01">
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl02_rdoCustomerSelect" type="radio" value="rdoCustomerSelect" title="rdo_ctl02">
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl03_rdoCustomerSelect" type="radio" value="rdoCustomerSelect" title="rdo_ctl03">
```

And so on...

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('input').attr('title', function () {
    var matches = $(this).attr('id').match(/ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_(.*)_rdoApplicantSelect/);
    return 'rdo_' + matches[1];
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ygSJf/)**

This generates:

```
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl01_rdoApplicantSelect" type="radio" value="rdoApplicantSelect" title="rdo_ctl01">
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl02_rdoApplicantSelect" type="radio" value="rdoApplicantSelect" title="rdo_ctl02">
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl03_rdoApplicantSelect" type="radio" value="rdoApplicantSelect" title="rdo_ctl03">
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl04_rdoApplicantSelect" type="radio" value="rdoApplicantSelect" title="rdo_ctl04">
<input id="ctl00_PageBody_grdCustomer_ctl05_rdoApplicantSelect" type="radio" value="rdoApplicantSelect" title="rdo_ctl05">
```

Comment: Beautiful! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split()`:

```
$('input').attr('title', function() {
    return 'rdo_' + this.id.split('_')[3]; 
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GyggJ/3/)

Comment: Very nice and compact! Works great!